# Timeout issue with Report server. Automatically refreshing Report Manager URL

Tags: powershell, reporting-services, server, reportmanager

I'm having an issue with Report Server. It takes so long to open a Report Manager url. Therefore, timeout issue occurs on Report Server.

What is the best way to auto start Report Manager URL?

My initial though was to use PowerShell script and Task Scheduler that will automatically run that script every week.

However, I couldn't find PowerShell script that can do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try to change in web.config of asp.net project

```
<system.web>
 <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="9999"/>
</system.web>
```

this may be helpfully instead of powershell script
    and also implement one handler script which may called every 5 seconds
    using jquery as like

```
public class SesstionHandler : IHttpHandler,IRequiresSessionState {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Session["KeepSessionAlive"] = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

and add this jquery at page level

```
$(function () {
    setInterval(KeepSessionAlive, 60000);
});

var i = 0;
function KeepSessionAlive() {
    i = i + 1;
    $.post( "SesstionHandler.ashx" , null, function () {
        .. some code here if needed
    });
}
```